# Split text at the right time in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text in a variable, for example: "Lancer Square super / CIT" and I would like to divide the text into 2 variables after the mark, namely: "Square super" and "CIT"

Comment: Take a look at String.split()

Comment: `"Lancer Square super / CIT".split(/\s*\/\s*/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place the results into 2 separate variables, try something like this:

```
var initialText =  "Lancer Square super / CIT";
var [string1, string2] = initialText.split(' / ');
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple

try this

```js
let str = "Lancer Square super / CIT";
let part1, part2;

part1 = str.split("/")[0].trim();
part2 = str.split("/")[1].trim();

console.log("part1 is: "+part1);
console.log("part2 is: "+part2);
```